# Cambiar cada carácter de un string de mayúscula a minúscula

Tags: java, string

Tengo un problema en el que el usuario introduce una string en mayúsculas y minúsculas y el programa tiene que dar esa string pero invirtiendo estas de minúsculas a mayúsculas. Ejemplo: HoLa--->hOlA.
He pensado en hacer una string auxiliar que sea la misma que introduce el usuario pero pasarla toda a minúscula y entonces ir comparando carácter a carácter pero no sé como llevar a cabo mi idea. Per charAt(i)!=charAt(i) no distingue mayúscula de minúscula. Tambien se que existe un código ascii pero me parece complicarse mucho y creo que tiene que haber una manera mas sencilla.

```
package Cadenas;
import java.util.*;
public class Ejercicio1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String usuario="";
        System.out.print("Introduce una palabra con mayusculas y minusculas");  
        usuario=sc.nextLine();
        String auxiliar=usuario.toLowerCase();
        for(int i=0;i<usuario.length();i++) {
            if(usuario.charAt(i)!=auxiliar.charAt(i)) {

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Buenas, yo de java no se nada, pero en la mayoría de los lenguajes existe una función tipo "toLowerCase" y "toUpperCase" para llevar una letra de mayúscula a minúscula y viceversa. Mi recomendación seria que tomes el string y analices indice a indice, y en cada uno de ellos con un if, en el caso que la letra sea mayuscula le aplicas toLowerCase y caso contrario aplicas toUpperCase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta es una solución basada en la clase `Character`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String usuario = "";
        System.out.print("Introduce una palabra con mayúsculas y minúsculas: ");
        usuario = sc.nextLine();
        String auxiliar = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < usuario.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isLowerCase(usuario.charAt(i))) {
                auxiliar += Character.toUpperCase(usuario.charAt(i));
            } else {
                auxiliar += Character.toLowerCase(usuario.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Salida: " + auxiliar);
    }
```

La idea esencial es utilizar el `wrapper` de `char` para utilizar los métodos que permitan comparar si la letra es mayúscula o minúscula y construir un `String` Auxiliar para ingresar la nueva palabra.

Answer (score 0):

`java` tiene una clase [`Character`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/character-class-java/) en la cual puedes comprobar si es una letra (`isLetter`), ahora cuando sabemos que es una letra comprobamos con una función de la misma clase si se encuentra en mayúscula, si es el caso entonces la pasamos con otra función 
a minúscula si no entonces a mayúscula.

Para utilizar esta clase es importante importarla

```
import java.lang.*;
```